# Getting input from users in Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a question about building a telegram bot with python.
How can I get input from the user in my python-telegram-bot?

For example, a dictionary bot, how can I get a word from the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend to have a look at the [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples).

With python-telegram-bot v12.0.0b1 you can do it like this:

```
def do_something(user_input):
    answer = "You have wrote me " + user_input
    return answer

def reply(update, context):
    user_input = update.message.text
    update.message.reply_text(do_something(user_input))

def main():
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, reply))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI), not python-telegram-bot.
For me it is easier.

And you should use this:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
  cid = message.chat.id
  mid = message.message_id 
  message_text = message.text 
  user_id = message.from_user.id 
  user_name = message.from_user.first_name
```

You can save this information in JSON if you want.

Comment: Can I know how to save the information in JSON?